# Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: c#, web-services, com-interop

I have a web form which is invoked over a web service (I'm afraid it has to run this way, due to a Com-Interop DLL which I have to call, and it requires a form...

When running this via a unit test style application to call this code, it works fine, and throws no errors.

However when invoked via a webserivce (and via thread to ensure it's single threaded), I am thrown the `Class not Reg'd` error.

Thoughts?

**Form Code:**

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ExtractorForm));
        this.axTTLogin1 = new AxTTLogin.AxTTLogin();
        this.axTTDocOp1 = new AxTTDOCOPLib.AxTTDocOp();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axTTLogin1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axTTDocOp1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // axTTLogin1
        // 
        this.axTTLogin1.Enabled = true;
        this.axTTLogin1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.axTTLogin1.Name = "axTTLogin1";
        this.axTTLogin1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axTTLogin1.OcxState")));
        this.axTTLogin1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 32);
        this.axTTLogin1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // axTTDocOp1
        // 
        this.axTTDocOp1.Enabled = true;
        this.axTTDocOp1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71, 13);
        this.axTTDocOp1.Name = "axTTDocOp1";
        this.axTTDocOp1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axTTDocOp1.OcxState")));
        this.axTTDocOp1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 32);
        this.axTTDocOp1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // ExtractorForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 62);
        this.Controls.Add(this.axTTDocOp1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.axTTLogin1);
        this.Name = "ExtractorForm";
        this.Text = "ExtractoFormr";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axTTLogin1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axTTDocOp1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private AxTTLogin.AxTTLogin axTTLogin1;
    private AxTTDOCOPLib.AxTTDocOp axTTDocOp1;
```

**Web Service Caller Code**

```
    public MemoryStream GetDocument(string ifnNumber, string disc, string set, string index3)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = null;

        Thread t = new Thread(() => ms = StartNewStaThread(_logger,ifnNumber,disc,set,index3));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        return ms;
    }

    private MemoryStream StartNewStaThread(Logger logger, string ifnNumber, string disc, string set, string index3)
    {
        _form = new ExtractorForm(_logger);
        return _form.GetDocument(ifnNumber, disc, set, index3);
    }
```

Comment: Do you target x86 or x64? See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20921638/1768303

Comment: I was trying both, and even running my app pool in 32-bit mode... after 3 days... I've fixed it, but I've no idea how :/